# Zip library options for the Compact Framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, zip, components

My requirements:

- Support .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and Windows Mobile 6.0 devices.
- Only need to unzip the contents to a directory on a storage card. Creation of zip files is not required.
- Must be able to use in corporate/commercial software.
- Can be open source, but not have GPL or other viral license.

I've seen the [Xceed Zip for CF](http://xceed.com/Zip_NET_CF_Intro.html) library. What other options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at #ziplib (www.icsharpcode.com). It's GPL, but you can use it in closed-source, commercial applications. They don't say anything specifically on their page about using it with the Compact Framework, so you'd have to give it a test yourself (that said, it's pure C# without any external dependencies, so the chances are somewhat good that it will work).

Answer (score 5):

As of v1.7, the DotNetZip distribution now includes a version built specifically for the .NET Compact Framework, either v2.0 or v3.5.   http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx.  It is about ~70k DLL. It does zip, unzip, zip editing, passwords, ZIP64, unicode, streams, and more.

DotNetZip is 100% managed code, open source, and free/gratis to use.  It's also very simple and easy.

```
  try
  {
      using (var zip1 = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
      {
          foreach (var entry in zip1)
          {
              entry.Extract(dir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
          }
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Exception! " + ex);
  }
```

There's a sample app included in the source distribution that unzips to a storage card.

[CF-Unzipper app http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ce5ad6a964.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ce5ad6a964.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why built for CF 3.5?  CF 3.5 *has* compression support built in.  It would be far more useful if it were built for 2.0, which there is still a significant install base and which *doesn't* have compression support.

Comment: Where in the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 are ZIP archives supported? System.IO.Compression is only for the deflate/gzip compression algorithms. They do NOT support the ZIP file format.

Comment: Both of you have points.  Ctacke, you're right, there are many more CF 2.0 devices around.  Slim - you are also correct:  the .NET Framework (desktop or CF, 3.5 or 2.0) does not provide built-in support for managing zips.  
In any case, I've updated v1.7 of DotNetZip so that it now runs on CF 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it may be a good option for you: http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip. It seems small, has source and has a very open license (MS-PL).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you need is zlibCE from the OpenNETCF foundation.
You can get it here: http://opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/zlibCE/tabid/245/Default.aspx

It's a port of the linux [zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) library to CE.  At it's core, it's a native dll, but they now also provide a .NET wrapper, along with all the source code.

I've used it in projects before and it performed quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Resco MobileForms toolkit for a variety of functionality: http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx

It includes a good ZIP library.