# Zip And Unzip files and folders

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, winapi, compact-framework

I need to zip and unzip the directory hirarchy in Windows Mobile using C++/C#. What is
the simplest library available for it?

I have googled many times. I found some stuff, but I am not able to go ahead with it.

If you have implemented or if you know some stuff about it please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

For .NET, [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

See also: [Zip library options for the Compact Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348/zip-library-options-for-the-compact-framework)

Comment: Hey, Thanks i will look into this..
i hope i will be able to zip entire directory and sub-directories

Answer (score 4):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) is a .NET library, has a build for .NET CF.

There's a .NET CF sample application delivered with the devkit.   It is a CF app that unzips files on the device.

[image]

The code that does the unzipping looks like this:

```
using (var zip1 = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(_selectedpath))
{
    foreach (var entry in zip1)
    {
        entry.Extract(dir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}

// now, re-populate the treeview with the extracted files:
AddChildren(tvFolders.SelectedNode.Parent);
```