# Creating a CAB file on WinCE

Tags: zip, windows-ce, cab

I want to make a CAB file on a WinCE 5/6 device.
The idea is that someone would run a backup script that creates the CAB file, which can then be loaded back onto the device at any point restoring settings to a previously known point.

The settings are xml and custom files in various folders on the device, I am not talking specifically about registry settings.

If this cannot be done is there (commercially) free ZIP file creation software that could be used?

Thankyou in advance
Chris

Comment: Thank you for removing the tag. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) is a free zip library that will let you do this.

See also:
[zip and unzip files and folders on Mobile Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706401/zip-and-unzip-files-and-folders/1723153#1723153)

Answer (score 0):

Is doing this from the desktop side any good?
You can use [this registry tool](http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/) using ActiveSync. The tool has a nice feature of Reg->CAB. Once you want to restore settings, you can clean the registry using `OALIoCtlHalGetHiveCleanFlag` and then run the CAB to restore the settings.

I know this does not include the requirement:

> run a backup script

But it is a quick solution that might give you an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the device runs stand alone and we want to be able to pull off some sort of backup archive via HTTP. A IIS plugin would generate the cab using code / application to send via HTTP.